# What should I do with the unknown 'Col_name' column in field list in mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE Bookinglog #########ROOMSTATE LOG TABLE 
(
 `Bookinglog_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 `Booking_ID` INT NOT NULL , 
 `time_stamp` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL ,
 `Booking_CheckInDate` date NOT NULL , 
 `Booking_CheckOutDate` date NOT NULL COMMENT , 
 `Cust_ID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT , 
 `booking_totalamount` INT NULL COMMENT,
 `LOG` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (Bookinglog_ID)
);
```

Mysql couldn't create a trigger for insert or delete, so I created one for each.

This is my trigger code :

```
select * from bookinglog;

drop table bookinglog;
drop trigger booking_trigger2;


############## Booking INSERT TRIGGER
delimiter $$ 
   create trigger Booking_trigger
    after insert on Booking
    for each row
    begin
      declare booking_id int;
      declare time_stamp timestamp;
      declare booking_checkindate date;
      declare booking_checkoutdate date;
      declare cust_id int;
      declare booking_totalamount int;
      declare log varchar(1);
      
      set booking_id = new.booking_id;
      set time_stamp = current_timestamp();
      set cust_id = new.cust_id;
      set booking_checkindate = new.booking_checkindate;
      set booking_checkoutdate = new.booking_checkoutdate;
      set booking_totalamount = new.booking_totalamount;
      set LOG = 'C';
      
      insert into roomstatelog(booking_id,time_stamp,booking_checkindate,booking_checkoutdate,cust_id,booking_totalamount,log) 
        value (booking_id,time_stamp,booking_checkindate,booking_checkoutdate,cust_id,booking_totalamount,log);
   end $$
delimiter ;

############## Booking DELETE TRIGGER
delimiter $$ 
   create trigger Booking_trigger2
    before delete on Booking
    for each row
    begin
      declare booking_id int;
      declare time_stamp timestamp;
      declare booking_checkindate date;
      declare booking_checkoutdate date;
      declare cust_id int;
      declare booking_totalamount int;
      declare log varchar(1);
      
      set booking_id = old.booking_id;
      set time_stamp = current_timestamp();
      set cust_id = old.cust_id;
      set booking_checkindate = old.booking_checkindate;
      set booking_checkoutdate = old.booking_checkoutdate;
      set booking_totalamount = old.booking_totalamount;
      set LOG = 'D';
      
      insert into roomstatelog(booking_id,time_stamp,booking_checkindate,booking_checkoutdate,cust_id,booking_totalamount,log) 
        value (booking_id,time_stamp,booking_checkindate,booking_checkoutdate,cust_id,booking_totalamount,log);
   end $$
delimiter ;
```

I want to log the data inserted or deleted from the reservation table in the bookinglog table.

When insert or delete is executed, these errors appear.

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'booking_checkindate' in 'field list'
```

I think there is a problem with the syntax in the trigger code

Comment: Check for case-sensitivity, column name in insert column list. try 'Booking_CheckInDate' rather than 'booking_checkindate'

Comment: @Suchitra I've checked it over and over. But I couldn't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was a really simple matter. I should write 'bookinglog' as the table name in insert into, but I wrote 'roomstate'.